# Check if a file ever existed and track its contents

Tags: log

I have an application that creates a directory and a key file within it. It uses it for a millisecond and then deletes the key once it is done using it.

How can I check if it ever successfully created the key file at a particular path and what it contained? Something like a `tail -f` on a file that may be created sometime in the future...

Comment: Are you the author of the application?

Comment: Nope, I'm treating it as a black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) ([manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html)).

If you know Python, use [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/).